# What regex expression will check GPS values?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm letting users enter GPS values through a form, they all have the same form, some examples:

```
49.082243,19.302628  

48.234142,19.200423  

49.002524,19.312578
```

I want to check the entered value using PHP (using `preg_match()`, I guess), but as I'm not good in regex expressions (oh, dumb me, I should finally learn it, I know), I don't know how to write the expression.

Obviously it should be:
2x (numbers), 1x (dot), 6x (numbers), 1x (comma), 2x (numbers), 1x (dot), 6x (numbers)

Any suggestions how to write this in regex?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Something like:

```
/^(-?\d{1,2}\.\d{6}),(-?\d{1,2}\.\d{6})$/
```

- `^` anchors at the start of input
- `-?` allows for, but does not require, a negative sign
- `\d{1,2}` requires 1 or 2 decimal digits
- `\.` requires a decimal point
- `\d{6}` requires exactly 6 decimal digits
- `,` matches a single comma
- (repeat the first 5 bullets)
- `$` anchors at the end of input

I have included capturing parentheses to allow you to extract the individual coordinates. Feel free to omit them if you don't need that.

All-around useful regex reference: http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

Comment: Beware that one GPS value is both those values separated by a comma.

Comment: Thanks, this is extremely helpful! Accepting your answer in 6 minutes, when the cooldown lets me :)

Comment: Just a quick fix, ^ is start of input and $ is end input

Comment: @Michael d'ahhh sloppy mistake. Good catch! Thanks, and fixed.

Comment: Another small gotcha, this will not let you enter in coordinates that are larger than 100 degrees. Both longitude and latitude is 180 to -180, the OP is wrong about his specs.

Comment: @Scott not quite. Latitude is only in `[-90, 90]` since `0°` is at the equator. The North Pole is at `90°` (lat) and the South Pole is at `-90°` (lat).

Comment: @Matt Ball I was fixing that but you caught me before I could change my edit post by 22 sec.

Answer (score 13):

The other answers I see don't take into account that longitude goes from -180 to 180 and latitude goes from -90 to 90.

The proper regex for this would be (assuming the order is "latitude, longitude"):

```
/^(-?[1-8]?\d(?:\.\d{1,6})?|90(?:\.0{1,6})?),(-?(?:1[0-7]|[1-9])?\d(?:\.\d{1,6})?|180(?:\.0{1,6})?)$/
```

This regex covers having no less than -90 and no more than 90 for latitude as well as no less than -180 and no more than 180 for longitude while allowing them to put in whole numbers as well as any number of decimal places from 1 to 6, if you want to allow greater precision just change {1,6} to {1,x} where x is the number of decimal place

Also, if you capture on group 1 you get the latitude and a capture on group 2 gets the longitude.

Answer (score 1):

```
/$-?\d{2}\.\d{6},-?\d{2}\.\d{6}^/
```

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on the other answer:

```
/^-?\d\d?\.\d+,-?\d\d?\.\d+$/
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example, this will do it:

```
if (preg_match('/(-?[\d]{2}\.[\d]{6},?){2}/', $coords)) {
    # Successful match
} else {
    # Match attempt failed
}
```

---

**Explanation:**

```
(          # Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
-          # Match the character “-” literally
?          # Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
[\d]       # Match a single digit 0..9
{2}        # Exactly 2 times
\.         # Match the character “.” literally
[\d]       # Match a single digit 0..9
{6}        # Exactly 6 times
,          # Match the character “,” literally
?          # Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
){2}       # Exactly 2 times
```